# How to set a scroll video's length to always match the page's height? (which can change with window resize and different devices)

Tags: javascript, scroll, html5-video

I have the following code which works fairly okay to set a video's current time to the page's scroll position:

```
var vid0 = document.getElementById('v0');
var scrollpos = 0; var targetscrollpos = 0; vid0.pause();  
 
window.onscroll = function(){ targetscrollpos = window.pageYOffset / 1700;};

setInterval(function(){   
    
  scrollpos += (targetscrollpos - scrollpos) * 0.25;
  vid0.currentTime = scrollpos; vid0.pause();
    
}, 40);
```

My issue is that this is independent of the page height - so you set the acceleration with a number, instead of calculating either that number from the page height or connect the page height somehow to the video's length, so when the user scrolls the video ends exactly when the document is scrolled all the way to the end.

The playback speed in this case would depend on the document length, which is absolutely fine and expected, I just have no idea how to go about this issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: here is a live example: https://adambernath.com/cc/scrollvid_bg_timing2.html
and here is the video file: https://storage.googleapis.com/vidijok/feketeauto_mobile.mp4
(The car turns a full 360 degree)

Comment: The Video duration property is a read-only property, so I guess the only possible way is to set the playback rate based on document.body.scrollHeight - somehow

Comment: and what I don't want is this: https://codepen.io/ollieRogers/pen/lfeLc/
I need to control the page height with other content, so i can't set the page height based on the video length - i have to set the video playback speed to match the page height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it.

```
var vid0 = document.getElementById('v0');
var scrollpos = 0; var targetscrollpos = 0; vid0.pause();    
    
window.onscroll = function(){     
    var vrate = document.body.scrollHeight / (vid0.duration * 1.1); 
    targetscrollpos = window.pageYOffset / vrate;};

setInterval(function(){   
  scrollpos += (targetscrollpos - scrollpos) * 0.25;
  vid0.currentTime = scrollpos; vid0.pause();   
}, 40);
```